# How to add a data frame with time delta?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

I have a dataframe `df2` and want to create a new time because of time differences. The csv-file wehere the dataframe comes from looks like:

```
ip           date            time                  zone
162.93.65.ggf   2014-03-06  2014-03-06 00:00:14 0
162.93.65.ggf   2014-07-10  2014-07-10 00:00:28 500
162.93.65.ggf   2013-11-21  2013-11-21 00:00:45 500
162.93.65.ggf   2014-02-22  2014-02-22 00:00:51 0
162.93.65.ggf   2014-03-06  2014-03-06 00:01:05 0
162.93.65.ggf   2013-11-21  2013-11-21 00:01:06 0
162.93.65.ggf   2014-02-22  2014-02-22 00:01:11 400
162.93.65.ggf   2014-03-06  2014-03-06 00:01:13 400
162.93.65.ggf   2013-11-21  2013-11-21 00:01:32 400
162.93.65.ggf   2014-03-06  2014-03-06 00:01:58 0
162.93.65.ggf   2013-11-21  2013-11-21 00:02:10 0
...
```

The column `zone` contains the values 0, 400 and 500 what means that the date times in `time` have to be add by 0, 4 or 5. After that there has to be add time and minutes depending on which time zone the ip address comes from.
My code :

```
df2 = pd.read_csv("file.csv", parse_dates=True)
df2['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['time'])
df2['zone2']= df2['zone'].astype(str).str[0]
df2['new_time']= df2['time']+ timedelta(hours=df2['zone2'])
```

hours and minutes are adjusted from another csv file what is to complicated to mention here and can be set as zero. The problem is in `hours=hours+df2['zone2']` but I don't to how to solve it..

My expected output is:

```
ip           date            time                  zone  new_time
162.93.65.ggf   2014-03-06  2014-03-06 00:00:14 0         2014-03-06 00:00:14
162.93.65.ggf   2014-07-10  2014-07-10 00:00:28 500       2014-07-10 05:00:28
162.93.65.ggf   2013-11-21  2013-11-21 00:00:45 500       2013-11-21 05:00:45   
162.93.65.ggf   2014-02-22  2014-02-22 00:00:51 0         ...
162.93.65.ggf   2014-03-06  2014-03-06 00:01:05 0
162.93.65.ggf   2013-11-21  2013-11-21 00:01:06 0
162.93.65.ggf   2014-02-22  2014-02-22 00:01:11 400
162.93.65.ggf   2014-03-06  2014-03-06 00:01:13 400
162.93.65.ggf   2013-11-21  2013-11-21 00:01:32 400
162.93.65.ggf   2014-03-06  2014-03-06 00:01:58 0
162.93.65.ggf   2013-11-21  2013-11-21 00:02:10 0
...
```

Comment: What is the `time` in your code?

Comment: `time`  is the column in my csv file i posted. The other time you can ignore I will edit it

Comment: what are you adding exactly ? just minutes? so the 2nd row would change from `00:00:28` to `00:00:32` show us your expected output.

Comment: So `zone`'s first letters are the hours that have to be added to `df['time']`, and rest of letters can be safely ignored?

Comment: have edit it for the first three rows of `new_time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the second and onward digits can be safely ignored,
use [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df['new_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['zone']/100, 'h')
print(df)
```

Output

```
               ip        date                 time  zone            new_time
0   162.93.65.ggf  2014-03-06  2014-03-06 00:00:14     0 2014-03-06 00:00:14
1   162.93.65.ggf  2014-07-10  2014-07-10 00:00:28   500 2014-07-10 05:00:28
2   162.93.65.ggf  2013-11-21  2013-11-21 00:00:45   500 2013-11-21 05:00:45
3   162.93.65.ggf  2014-02-22  2014-02-22 00:00:51     0 2014-02-22 00:00:51
4   162.93.65.ggf  2014-03-06  2014-03-06 00:01:05     0 2014-03-06 00:01:05
5   162.93.65.ggf  2013-11-21  2013-11-21 00:01:06     0 2013-11-21 00:01:06
6   162.93.65.ggf  2014-02-22  2014-02-22 00:01:11   400 2014-02-22 04:01:11
7   162.93.65.ggf  2014-03-06  2014-03-06 00:01:13   400 2014-03-06 04:01:13
8   162.93.65.ggf  2013-11-21  2013-11-21 00:01:32   400 2013-11-21 04:01:32
9   162.93.65.ggf  2014-03-06  2014-03-06 00:01:58     0 2014-03-06 00:01:58
10  162.93.65.ggf  2013-11-21  2013-11-21 00:02:10     0 2013-11-21 00:02:10
```

Comment: nice and clean, was just about to post my answer but realised it's the same as yours!